# Eindeutigkeit bei der Nutzung von Kommentaren

Tags: technical-terminology, ambiguity

Ein Mehrdeutigkeitsproblem aus der Programmierung:

Schreibt man Code, gibt es Zeilen die vom Programm ausgeführt werden sollen und einige die nur für Programmierer gedacht sind. Letztere nennt man Kommentare.

In Python kann man beispielsweise ein Rautezeichen (#) und bei Transact SQL (TSQL) zwei Minuszeichen (--) voranstellen.

- Beispiel Python:

  ```
  #Dies ist ein Kommentar.
  ```
- Beispiel TSQL:

  ```
  --Dies ist ein Kommentar.
  ```

Aber gibt es eine nicht mehrdeutige Möglichkeit zu beschreiben, dass ich diese Zeichen hinzufüge oder entferne?

Mir scheint als wären "kommentieren" und "auskommentieren" gängige Begriffe. Abgeleitet vom Englischen "comment" und "uncomment".

Leider ist "auskommentieren" problematisch. Warum? "Auskommentieren" soll heißen, dass die Kommentarzeichen (# oder --) entfernt werden sollen. Aber, kommentierte Zeilen werden vom Programm nicht gelesen. Sie wurden aus dem Programm herauskommentiert. Es kann also passieren dass jemand der "auskommentieren" ließt, Kommentarzeichen hinzufügt statt sie zu entfernen.

Gibt es dazu eine Richtlinie um Eindeutigkeit sicherzustellen?

Das beste was ich finden konnte war in einer Dokumentation von Microsoft in der von "Kommentare auflösen" gesprochen wurde um zu meinen, dass Kommentarzeichen entfernt werden sollen.

Comment: Das Problem scheint mir keins zu sein, weil der Kontext immer Eindeutigkeit herstellt: Wenn eine Zeile  Code bereits auskommentiert ist, kann _auskommentieren_ in Bezug auf sie ja nur das Entfernen des Kommentars bedeuten, sie kann ja nicht zweimal vom Compiler ignoriert werden.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: Was bedeutet dann beispielsweise eine Aussage wie "Die Dokumentationsgenerierung wird jedes Mal automatisch neu angestoßen, wenn eine Zeile auskommentiert wird"? Da sich die Aussage nicht auf eine konkrete Zeile bezieht, ist ja eben unbekannt, ob "die Zeile" ein Kommentar ist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man kann sich vielleicht der Bedeutung des Verbs *auskommentieren* nähern, indem man sich fragt, wie man den zugehörigen Zustand nennt:

```
DoSomething();
//log.Debug("Ende von Teil 1 erreicht.");
DoSomeOtherThing();
```

Den Zustand der zweiten Zeile würde ich nur und ausschließlich als *auskommentiert* bezeichnen, fast nur so kenne ich das auch aus Literatur (Ausnahme s.u.). Ich würde nie sagen, die Zeile sei *kommentiert*.

Das *Auskommentieren* einer Zeile Code ist demnach also der Vorgang, den Code weg vom wirksamen Zustand in einen Kommentar umzuwandeln. So sieht es auch z.B. [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/auskommentieren).

Aber wie heißt der umgekehrte Vorgang? Im Englischen offenbar *to uncomment*. Im Deutschen kenne ich dafür kein Wort. Ich benutze salopp "die Zeile reinnehmen" oder eine Umschreibung à la "die Auskommentierung rückgängig machen". Ich könnte mir auch vorstellen, einfach den Anglizismus *unkommentieren* zu verwenden, bisher tue ich das aber nicht.

Handübersetzte deutsche Dokumentationen für IDEs findet man z.B. noch bei Microsoft. Deren Übersetzer benutzt in der [Hilfe zu den Tastenkombinationen in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#bkmk_edit-popular-shortcuts) "Auswahl kommentieren" beziehungsweise "Auskommentierung der Auswahl aufheben". Das heißt, der Übersetzer wusste zwar sehr genau, wie *Auskommentierung* definiert ist, hat sich aber aus irgendwelchen Gründen trotzdem für *Auswahl kommentieren* entschieden.

Comment: Wäre die natürliche Begriffsbildung als Gegensatz zu "auskommentieren" nicht einfach "einkommentieren"? Wobei "rein" und "raus" dann eigentlich eh logischer wären, oder?

Comment: @Lykanion Das Problem dabei ist, denke ich, dass schon das Grundverb "Kommentieren" eigentlich nur für die eine Richtung passt, nämlich aus Code einen Kommentar machen. "Auskommentieren" macht es nur deutlicher. Die andere Richtung ist einfach kein "Kommentieren", deshalb bräuchte man eine verneinende Vorsilbe wie un- oder ent-.

Answer (score 4):

Ich verstehe die Begriffe im Kontext des Codierens von Software wie folgt:

1. **kommentieren**
   Einen Text in natürlicher Sprache schreiben, dessen Lektüre es einem zukünftigen menschlichen Leser des Quellcodes erleichtert, den Sinn des Quellcodes zu verstehen. Um zu verhindern, dass der Interpreter oder Compiler versucht, diesen Text als Befehle der Programmiersprache zu interpretieren, wird dieser Text mit einem Kommentarzeichen als nichtausführbarer Bestandteil des Quellcodes gekennzeichnet.
2. **auskommentieren**
   Eine Zeile (oder eine zusammenhängende Folge von Zeilen), die Code enthält, der vom Compiler in eine ausführbare Anweisung übersetzt oder vom Interpreter als Anweisung ausgeführt werden kann, wird durch das Hinzufügen eines Kommentarzeichens als nichtausführbarer Bestandteil des Quellcodes gekennzeichnet. Das Übersetzen bzw. Interpretieren dieser Programmzeile(n) wird dadurch verhindert.

Um diese beiden Fälle zu unterscheiden, hat sich in vielen Programmiersprachen die Konvention etabliert, diese beiden Arten von Kommentaren mit unterschiedlich vielen Kommentarzeichen zu versehen:

- Kommentare vom Typ 1 (Erklärungen in natürlicher Sprache) werden mit 2 oder 3 Kommentarzeichen eingeleitet
- Kommentare vom Typ 2 (Deaktivierungen von ausführbarem Code) werden mit nur einem Kommentarzeichen eingeleitet

Auch schon gesehen: Bei Kommentaren vom Typ 1 schreibt man ein Leerzeichen hinter dem Kommentarzeichen, beim Typ 2 folgt der auskommentierte Code unmittelbar auf das Kommentarzeichen (ohne Leerzeichen dazwischen). Eine weitere Möglichkeit bieten Sprachen, in denen es zwei verschiedene Arten von Kommentaren gibt (meist Zeilenkommentare und Blockkommentare). Auch damit kann man Erläuterungen von deaktiviertem Code unterscheiden.

Beispiele:

```
### Entfernen Sie das Kommentarzeichen, um eine
### der folgenden Optionen zu aktivieren.  
# debug_mode
# force
verbose_output
# use_GPU

# Entfernen Sie das Kommentarzeichen, um eine
# der folgenden Optionen zu aktivieren.  
#debug_mode
#force
verbose_output
#use_GPU

=begin
= Entfernen Sie das Kommentarzeichen, um eine
= der folgenden Optionen zu aktivieren.  
=end
# debug_mode
# force
verbose_output
# use_GPU
```

3. **das Auskommentieren Rückgängig machen**
   Es gibt im Deutschen aber leider kein gängiges Verb, das die Umkehrung des in (2) beschriebenen Verbs *auskommentieren* bedeutet. Im Englischen ist seit langem schon das Verb *to uncomment* etabliert, das genau diesen Vorgang beschriebt, aber im Deutschen bleibt einem kaum etwas besseres übrig, als *Auskommentieren rückgängig machen* zu sagen.
   Ich möchte dringend davor warnen, dass Verb *»auskommentieren«*, das bereits einigermaßen gut mit der Bedeutung *»Code deaktivieren«* belegt ist, für das exakte Gegenteil dieser Aktion zu verwenden. Denn erst dadurch entsteht überhaupt erst das Problem, das in der Frage thematisiert wurde.

Comment: "Es gibt im Deutschen aber leider kein gängiges Verb, das die Umkehrung (...) bedeutet." Ich kenne und verwende dafür "einkommentieren", aber ich kann nicht sagen, wie allgemein etabliert das ist.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: Ich würde mal sagen, dass *»einkommentieren«* gar nicht etabliert ist. Das Wort kam mir mir zwar in den Sinn, als ich meine Antwort schrieb, und ein Gegenteil von *»auskommentieren«* suchte, aber gleichzeitig bemerkte ich, dass ich es noch nie benutzt und auch noch nie gehört/gelesen habe. Wiktionary kennt auch nur [auskommentieren](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/auskommentieren), nicht aber [einkommentieren](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/einkommentieren). (In DWDS und Duden steht nicht mal *auskommentieren.*)

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: Ich wäre bin mit dem Verb *extrem* vorsichtig. Ja, es ist mir schon begegnet, und aus dem Kontext wurde meist klar, was gemeint war. Jedoch scheint mir durch Hinzunahme jenes Verbs die Verwirrung komplett zu sein, denn sowohl die Interpretation "'auskommentieren' bedeutet, etwas in einen Kommentar zu verwandeln und 'einkommentieren' macht Selbiges rückgängig" als auch "'einkommentieren' bedeutet, etwas in einen Kommentar zu verwandeln ('einpacken' -> 'in die Verpackung tun'; 'eintüten' -> 'in die Tüte tun'; 'einkommentieren' -> 'in den Kommentar tun') und ...

Comment: ... 'auskommentieren' holt Selbiges wieder *aus* dem Kommentar heraus" scheinen beide völlig plausibel.

Answer (score 2):

#### dekommentieren

ist eine Möglichkeit, aber auch

#### entkommentieren

Gebräuchlich ist beides nicht, aber wird wohl von den Meisten, die dezentralisieren und entvölkern verstanden haben, verstanden.